# How do I connect to a SockJS server from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a SockJS server running in Node.js. Now I would like to connect to this server, not from a browser, but from another Node.js server.

[sockjs-client](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) is browser only, and [sockjs-node](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) does not provide a client part.

Of course I could use a module such as [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) (or any other module which is RFC 6455-compliant), but then I lose all the nice functionality of the SockJS server such as fallbacks et al.

How can I connect to SockJS from Node.js?

Comment: Why do you want the fallbacks?

Comment: Because I want to do unit testing and I want to use the same client API on the server as I use within the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sockjs-client` from node too. Check the following packages:

1. [sockjs-client](https://npmjs.org/package/sockjs-client)    only XHR Streaming transport
2. [sockjs-client-ws](https://npmjs.org/package/sockjs-client-ws)    only WebSocket transport

Comment: Care to share how? The following doesn't work:

 var sockjsClient = require('sockjs-client');
 var clientSocket = new sockjsClient(url);
 clientSocket.onopen(function(){console.log('connected')});

Comment: @blented Doesn't work is too vague. You should ask another question specifying the code and errors you get. This answer solves a different problem.